# Using Java for loops to make a times table

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to make a Java program that creates multiplication tables using nested for loops by asking the user for upper bounds and display the following result such as this (first image attached). [Desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH5h7.jpg)

However, my code is causing it the program to only print out the multiple of the two inputs and looping that the same amount of times as the multiple. For example in here (second image attached), if it put in the input as 3 and 5, it is displaying 15 to me 15 times. [My displayed format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDUDX.jpg)

This is what my code looks like (last image attached):

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gmyO.jpg)

Thank you all so much in advance. Please help me out!!! I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: don't provide code as images

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int firstFactor = 0;
        int secondFactor = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter the first factor: ");
        firstFactor = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second factor: ");
        secondFactor = s.nextInt();
        for(int i=1; i<=firstFactor; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=secondFactor; j++) {
                System.out.println(i + " * " + j + " = " + i*j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the first factor: 3
Enter the second factor: 5
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
1 * 4 = 4
1 * 5 = 5

2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
2 * 5 = 10

3 * 1 = 3
3 * 2 = 6
3 * 3 = 9
3 * 4 = 12
3 * 5 = 15
```

**Modifications:**

1. Change `firstFactor*secondFactor` to `i*j`. Since `firstFactor was 3` and `secondFactor was 5`. Hence you were getting `15` as an output each time.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest not using an image for your code. You can just add it as part of your question using the provided edit tools (or Ctrl+k).
Anyway, from a quick look your code looks fine with one bug. You just need to do this:

```
System.out.println(i*j)
```

Where you had:

```
System.out.println(firstFactor*secondFactor)
```

Those are set to input values and do not change during the loop.

Comment: Or more precisely, 
`System.out.println(i + "*" + j + " = " + (i * j));`

Comment: Got it!! Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Do you know how I can add a line break after every times table? Like how after the first table there's a line break and another one after the second table and so on...

Comment: Look at the answer from @Nitin above. Simply put you just add a System.out.println() after the inner loop (i.e. the loop that iterates over j items).

Answer (score 0):

Change your first and second factor to i and j.

```
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<=5; j++) {
            System.out.print("i: "+i+" j: "+j);
            System.out.println(" Value: "+i*j);
        }
    }
```